# "invalid version 0 on git_proxy_options" from libgit2: cause? fix? walk-around?

Tags: libgit2

I'm getting this error "invalid version 0 on git_proxy_options" from libgit2. This did not happen until very recently (I have recompiled my code so it may be a version issue). I'm not using a proxy. Does anyone know anything about this? What causes this message? Is there anything I can do to stop the failure? Either a fix or or a work-around will do.

Specifically, I am using the Rust crate git2 version 0.13.23. I am doing a fetch that triggers the error. This is on Fedora 34 on x86_64. I have searched on this but there does not seem to be any matches that help.

Answer (score 2):

```
git2 = {version="0.13.22", features = ["vendored-libgit2"]}
```

in `Cargo.toml` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting...

I had upgraded libgit2 to 1.3.0 from 1.1.1.  That broke my existing cargo install, so I unpacked the previous libgit2.so.1.1 with a symlink to libgit2.so.1.  That's when this error condition showed up.  After thinking a bit I decided to symlink libgit2.so.1.3 to libgit2.so.1.1 and it built my new cargo version which linked to the new libgit2.so.1.3.  Then I deleted my libgit2.so.1.1 stuff.  Kinda weird, and usually you expect things not to work when it has been linked to a previous .so version.